# How do I correctly write a 2D plotting call in SymPy with a logarithmic x-axis?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm attempting to plot a function in SymPy using a logarithmic x-axis.  However, when I set the range it appears to use the log of the specified range instead of the range itself.

I've tried this in Jupyter Notebook, running Python 3.7.4 and SymPy 1.4.  I also tried this in a command line Python instance, with the same result.

```py
from sympy import init_session
from sympy.plotting import  plot
init_session()
plot(x, (x, 100e3, 10e6), xscale='log')
```

There is a screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLvua.jpg

As noted, the range of the x-value that's returned appears to be a log10 of the values fed into the plot function.  (Log10(100e3)=5, Log10(10e6)=7).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was fixed in the PR [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/16796). Have you tried downloading a current version?

Comment: Ah pefect, thanks!  I updated to the latest git pull of sympy and the issue is resolved.     Hopefully 1.5 releases before I finish up this project.